# Cannot rm or chown /var/log/snort as root

Tags: permissions, root, snort

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 Gnome.

I installed an older version of Snort, uninstalled it and tried to install the latest version as root using sudo. However, the install crashed because root does not have permission to change or remove /var/log/snort. I thought root was supposed to have permission to do anything. I cannot even change or rm the directory, or its contents when I su.

```
ls -ld /var/log/snort
```

returns

```
drwxr-s--- 2 snort adm 4096 2013-05-16 21:17 /var/log/snort
```

Can anyone suggest a resolution to this problem.

Thanks,
Peter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, root has rights to do anything on the system, at least if nothing important is seriously broken. To become root:

`sudo su`

If the given directory in not empty, a recursive remove needs to be used:

`rm -r /var/log/snort`

However if any of the files in that directory are open, the operation still may be refused.

To change owner, simply use:

`chown root /var/log/snort`

If all of this doesn't work, boot in with an Ubuntu CD/USB installer and run `fsck` on the filesystem. Even if it seems clean, it might be easier to remove the directory with the live system.

By the way, Ubuntu 11.10 is not supported anymore, please `dist-upgrade` or install a newer distribution (12.04 LTS or 13.04).

Comment: I did "sudo su" went to /var/log and did "rm -r snort".  I got a bunch of error messages like "rm: cannot remove `snort/tcpdump.log.1362660537': Operation not permitted".  "chown root /var/log/snort" resulted in "chown: changing ownership of `/var/log/snort': Operation not permitted" despite the fact I was logged in as root.  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: the files are owned by adm but "sudo su adm" results in "Unknown id: adm".

Comment: It seems like those files are open. Are you sure that `snort` isn't running? Use `su snort` as root to try it as the owner, `adm` is the owner group's name.

Comment: I closed all of my shell terminals so there should not have been an instance of snort running.  I also did "snort" when logged in as root.  I had uninstalled snort so it was not able to run although the log files were there and I could not get rid of them.  "ps -aux |grep snort" returned "root     13275  0.0  0.0   4212   764 pts/0    S+   21:38   0:00 grep --color=auto snort".  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: It's not running then. Check the relevant open files with `lsof | grep /var/log/snort`

Comment: This only output I got was "lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/peter/.gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete."

Comment: Run `updatedb` and try again.

Comment: Same result. "root@peter-Inspiron-620:/var/log# updatedb
You have new mail in /var/mail/root
root@peter-Inspiron-620:/var/log# lsof | grep /var/log/snort
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/peter/.gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
root@peter-Inspiron-620:/var/log#

Comment: Strange, seems like no file is open in there. Boot in with the Ubuntu installer in live mode, mount the filesystem and delete what you want.